# TypeScript - strong typing for arrays merged to single array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have a JS function that accepts an array of arrays (of same length, but different types), and an array of key names (one for each array in the first parameter), and merges the arrays together into an array of objects. Like this:

```js
const mergeArraysToSeries = (arrs, keys) => {
  const merged = [];

  for (let dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < arrs[0].length; dataIndex++) {
    const el = keys.reduce((combined, currKey, keyIndex) => {
      const val = arrs[keyIndex][dataIndex];
      return { ...combined, [currKey]: val };
    }, {});
  
    merged.push(el);
  }

  return merged;
}

const example = mergeArraysToSeries([[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']], ['num', 'letter'])
// example = [{num: 1, letter: 'a'}, {num: 2, letter: 'b'}, {num: 3, letter: 'c'}]
```

Is there a way to write this in TypeScript that would give good autocomplete on the merged array, as well as correctly map the types for each key? For the above example, I'd like the compiler to know that the type of `example[0].num` is `'number'`

I've gotten to a place where I can have auto complete / compiler checking for the property names of each item in the result array, but am unsure how to get the correct type for each element to come through. The type signature looks like this right now:

```
const mergeArrayToSeries = <K>(arrs: any[][], keys: (keyof K)[]): Record<keyof K, any>[] => ...
```

Is there a good way to remove those `any`s for the passed arrays, and have the type safety described above?

Thanks!

Edit: I'd like this to work for an arbitrary number of arrays you want to merge if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a signature like this one:

```
declare function mergeArraysToSeries<
  T extends any[],
  U extends any[],
  P1 extends string,
  P2 extends string
>(arrays: [T, U], properties: [P1, P2]): {
    [K in P1]: T[number]
  } & {
    [K in P2]: U[number]
  }[];

const example = mergeArraysToSeries([[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']], ['num', 'letter']); // example is { num: number; letter: string }[]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=75#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsQYBzEAQRhigE8BnAFRwGVisQ6AeAKHngfggAHhhCpgdeFFQ0A2gF0ANL3gBVQSLESpMhcr4AFAIwbR4yXQwwsqEvvgGATKa0WrNktwB8ACljV6AC54WQZFNSV4AAcYHCjibA5g2WNwp3kASmCAYRwCKKhMHj4AbxU%20WQBpeBsHI3lghllUZAIAI2J5FQBfeAAyeDK%20Cura9ODVZtaOmC6%20bpUvBQBubm4AegAqTd5N-ixsaQByOgA6AAsMDCi6QPX1kgPz5DbTsDz1giwwWLocRAw6wYNHizB%20WCigKwdDoyA46yMABYAByOACcAGJobDwHkiKgMABaADMjgADAB2ACsiIpxKMu3W3AwIIQuXyhQwnAYXngAF5Br0BiUQgYavgANYgGj-fgNfgpeTwbqrbjvVCWDRQfIQBACoikChUWiMFhsDg%20WSyIyKRyKYmRWRHKBHRRHNquo5gI7yR1HFoEV3wI66q7EH0ZZbwe5anUIaGDeAB4IBmZR0OiGDBSzWWzKhTcIA)

**Update**

If you need to support more than two arrays, you can add more overloads.

```
declare function mergeArraysToSeries<T, U, P extends readonly string[]>(arrays: [T[], U[]], properties: P): { [K in P[0]]: T } & { [K in P[1]]: U }[]
declare function mergeArraysToSeries<T, U, V, P extends readonly string[]>(arrays: [T[], U[], V[]], properties: P): { [K in P[0]]: T } & { [K in P[1]]: U } & { [K in P[2]]: V }[]
declare function mergeArraysToSeries<T, U, V, W, P extends readonly string[]>(arrays: [T[], U[], V[], W[]], properties: P): { [K in P[0]]: T } & { [K in P[1]]: U } & { [K in P[2]]: V } & { [K in P[3]]: W }[]

const two = mergeArraysToSeries([[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']], ['num', 'letter'] as const)
const three = mergeArraysToSeries([[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']], ['num', 'letter', 'other'] as const)
const four = mergeArraysToSeries([[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], [0, 0, 0]], ['num', 'letter', 'other', 'index'] as const)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=43#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsQYBzEAQRhigE8BnAFRwGVisQ6AeBgGngFU+ABXggAHhhCpgdeHCjA8EGvDoYYWVCQDaAXQB8ACljV6ALnjaGevvz26+ABxg5HxbBwtCAlBYDelgDS8JrwQtoADLq6FgzwAL7wAGTwAdrBoeEAjNEW-Al6AFCgkLAIKOjYeITEZJSmjCxsHNy2fABqwqISUjJyIApKKmoaWnpGJrR0FlY2AnPt9k4ubjAe02G+qUEh+OFRMfBxiSlpGXvaOYf5J9vpu2HaAEy58O0FusXg0HBIaJi4fBEUgUKhTJisDQtXgCDp8ADqXXEkmksnkilQylU6k0OgMxjB5ks1gc81Ji1J8KW8Gcrnc7A2Pn8O0ykVex2Sd3OjyueQSnLOD3CL0O71ugtZAGZXvCPoVCmA8Gp4BgAO44eAAXhqIPq4KaULohm0lz4Tz40r42gA5FBrXxrQAje3wa1ga3RK3W1DIAgu60QEAYSQwD3wKCyRWoNTeBVKjAqgAWcAQ2uBdUJjUhDONpvg5vglsstv9zod7tJNsQOBwpdgdYAXh7K97ff7A8HiP6cBhE13dOHI-HY1HldXkDAtTqMw0Ic0jSasmaLS27Q6y66K17q7X1-W903KxE+Mf4AcvT6-Q6OyHu72uw7NKAxGGI-BRxhvEA)

Comment: Cool! I haven't seen the `T[number]` syntax before in a definition. 

I think this works for when you want to merge two arrays/properties. I probably should have clarified this in the question, but I'm looking to make this function accept an arbitrary number of array / property combinations in the inputs. Do you know of a way to  express that?

Comment: Just to clarify: the last array (property names) can be arbitrarily long, and by implication, the first array will contain any number of arrays inside? This *may* be possible, but I already feel that the implementation will be horribly complicated. Maybe it's easier to use overloads instead?

Comment: Yes, the array of arrays and the array of property names will have the same length, but that length is not know until the function is used.  

For example, I might provide an array of 5 arrays (with different types as in the example) and provide 5 property keys, and the resulting array will have objects with 5 properties. Does that make sense? 

How could an overload be used here? I haven’t used those beyond simple function parameter overloads before.

Comment: I updated my answer to show what it would look like. It handles up to 4 properties, but you can add more based on the ones I provided.

Comment: Thanks! That is clear and gets the job done. It would be really nice if there was a way pair types based on a dynamic index, rather than specify something like `[K in P[0]]: T` explicitly. Like `[K in P[n]]: T[n]`. I wonder if there is a way to do this with indexes.